# Why was there silence in heaven for half an hour? Is the time significant?

Tags: revelation

> Revelation 8:1: When the Lamb opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven for about half an hour...

Why silence in heaven for half hour? why 1/2 hour? Is the timing is important?
Thanks...

Comment: And its significant that there are 24 hours in a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the various lengths of time mentioned in the Revelation are significant. Half an hour is one of the shortest ones. So, what does the text tell us? It gives a sequence of events. And here I quote from a book explaining this sequence and the significance of the time factor.

> "There is silence in heaven for half an hour. The seven angels are
> manifested and given seven trumpets. The angel appears with the
> censer. Much incense is given. The smoke ascends to God and fire of
> the altar is cast into the earth, with alarming effect.
>
> Thereupon the seven angels prepare to sound, and begin their sounding
> with the blowing of the first trump (vs.7). If so, the preceding
> verses of Chapter 8 - that is, vv.1-6 - reveal that upon which the
> sounding of the seven trumpets is based. The trumpet blasts
> precipitate in turn a series of catastrophes that come down upon the
> earth. But neither do the trumpets sound, nor the catastrophes fall,
> until after the first six verses.
>
> Since the seven angels with the seven trumpets do not bring down the
> series of disastrous calamities until Revelation 8:7, it follows
> therefore that the cause of these judgments sent from heaven is
> discovered by the opening of what took place in heaven prior to their
> commencement. This is recorded in Revelation 8:1-6...
>
> But - after the seventh seal was broken open by the Lamb - *why* was
> there silence in heaven for half an hour? Half an hour is not a long
> period. On the other hand it is not too short. A few minutes would be
> too short, but an hour might well be considered too long. Half an hour
> is a distinctive enough period, a sufficiently long pause, to indicate
> a decent interval, but no more than a decent interval. Enough for all
> heaven to stop, to be still.
>
> Silence pertains to the ear. It is what is required if something is to
> be heard by those who listen. They are not making the noise. They are
> not making a soud. The noise comes from elsewhere. And all heaven is
> still during this sufficient interval to catch the sound. What sound?
>
> Since the following verses show that the prayers of all saints are
> ascending into the silence of heaven, for long enough an interval for
> heaven to catch all that is breathed; to hear every sigh; and to
> listen to each one of the groanings; indeed, to detect even the near
> silent drop of every tear; the whisper of every lip: then the reason
> for the silence is confirmed.
>
> That is why there is silence in heaven, because by this, in a figure,
> God is assuring his elect that all heaven - in a moment, in one brief,
> but very distinct interval - inclines to hear the very words and sighs
> breathed from the saints below...
>
> Revelation 5:8 manifests the things in heaven, and speaks of the
> golden vials full of odours 'which are the prayers of saints'.
> Likewise Revelation 8:3 declares 'the prayers of all saints.' The
> opening of the fifth seal revealed the souls of them which were under
> the altar, slain for the word of God, and for the testimony which they
> held. This was their prayer: 'How long, O Lord, holy and true, dost
> thou not judge and avenge our blood on them that dwell on the earth?'
> Rev.6:10.
>
> With this prayer. Revelation 8:3 agrees. If these are the prayers of
> the suffering saints on earth, and if the prayers of all saints are
> preceded by the symbol of silence in heaven, and followed by the
> figure of prayer ascending up as incense, the cause of the silence in
> heaven is no longer a matter of conjecture.
>
> Here is metaphorical language. Truth is conveyed by figures: by
> pictorial imagery. Silence therefore answers to the quiet command in
> heaven to give ear to the prayers of all saints. It is all saints to
> whom the God  of heaven is listening. In connection with those prayers
> the seal had been broken and the seven angels with the seven trumpets
> appear. Luke 18:7,8" *The Revelation of Jesus Christ* pp. 213-216,
> John Metcalfe

To understand this one verse, the sequence of events must be understood in how they relate to what it is that heaven stays silent for. Then the significance of the interval of silence might be understood. I hope this quote details this enough to help you on your way in understanding this part of the Revelation. Much more understanding can be gained from the entire 614-page book.

Comment: EXCELENT!!! The above captures .... "the half hour of silence" perfectly. Nicely projected indeed, + 1.

Answer (score 4):

The seventh seal introduces the seven trumpet judgments of God.  The judgments that lead up to the close of the tribulation are so severe that a solemn silence falls upon all of heaven.  For heaven to fall silent, to cease the constant praises of God, is dramatic indeed.  Silence is a powerful instrument and suggests a need to stop, think and reflect upon what is about to transpire.

Seven angels are then handed seven trumpets ready to sound (verse 2).  An eighth angel takes a censer and burns “much incense” in it, representing the prayers of God’s people (verses 3–4).  The angel then fills the censer, “with fire from the altar” then hurls it on the earth, followed by “peals of thunder, rumblings, flashes of lightning and an earthquake” (verse 5).

My NLT Study Bible makes this comment about Revelation 8:1 in the notes:

> “The opening of the seventh seal concludes the first act and dramatically initiates silence, which suggests the mystery of God in his dealings with the world (see Revelation 10:4; 1 Kings 19:11-12).  Perhaps the mysterious silence here is analogous to God’s rest on the seventh day of creation (Genesis 2:1-3).  This brief hush precedes the unfolding of the second act of divine judgment when God will answer the prayers of his people.”

My ESV Study Bible says this:

> “The silence in heaven that ensues when the Lamb breaks the seventh seal further sustains the suspense... The brief period of silence – about half an hour – displaces ceaseless praises by living creatures, elders, angels, and the church triumphant.  Silence is appropriate in anticipation of the Lord’s coming judgment (Zephaniah 1:7-10; Zechariah 2:13).”

“About half an hour” may not have any significance, given the astonishing events the Apostle John saw.  The element of time, linear and familiar to humans, may be inadequate to express properly what was being revealed in heaven.  It is possible that in the revelation only a short period of time elapsed while the angels prepared themselves for what was to come.  Whatever the reason for the silence, and its duration, it precedes earth-shattering events, and that should be sufficient to warn us of the terrible nature of the events that accompany the seven trumpets.

Edit: Whilst some denominations adopt a literalist interpretation of Revelation, I believe that the numbers convey ideas, not arithmetic. Forms display concepts, not shapes. Words are clothed in mystery, not logic.  I do not think there is any reason to believe that the 30 minutes of silence in heaven is a literal 30 minutes measured by humans. It is simply a period of time that allows, for example, the prayers of the martyred saints to cry out to God for the avenging of the murder of His people (Revelation 6:9). Also for His church below to likewise cry out for the return of our Lord and Saviour. Such heartfelt prayers to God have been ascending into heaven for the past 2,000 years and will continue to do so till God intervenes in the affairs of men and brings an end to the evil that now permeates this world.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand what you mean by the all merciful God being rendered merciless.  Along with God's mercy comes justice.  I like your idea of heaven being rendered silent because of empathy for what is to come. Neither God, nor the Lamb, nor the angels would ever take delight in what is about to transpire. But God can never allow sin and rebellion against Him to go unpunished. Would you agree?  Nonetheless, who are we to argue against God's sovereign right to dispense justice?  If I've misunderstood your comments, please clarify.

Comment: That’s very interesting.  It had not crossed my mind to consider the execution of justice beyond the boundaries of planet Earth.  Yes, lawbreakers have to be brought to justice.  Oh, and I’m a madam, not a sir (Lesley is the feminine version of the masculine Scottish place name Leslie).  However, we must not get off-topic!

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah is in His holy temple: be silent before Him, all the earth!
Hush, all flesh, before Jehovah! For He is roused up from His holy habitation.
Be silent before the Lord Jehovah, for the day of Jehovah is near; for Jehovah has prepared a sacrifice; He has consecrated those whom He has called.
Be still and know that I am God. I will be exalted among the nations; I will be exalted on earth.
And they answered the Angel of Jehovah, who was standing among the myrtle trees, and they said, We have gone to and fro on the earth, and indeed all the earth sits still and is quiet.

Hab 2:20; Zech 2:13; Zeph 1:7; Psa 46:10; Zech 1:11.

And when He opened the seventh seal, there was silence in heaven for about half an hour. And I saw the seven angels who stand before God, and seven trumpets were given to them. And another Angel came and stood at the altar, having a golden censer, and much incense was given to Him to offer with the prayers of all the saints upon the golden altar which was before the throne. And the smoke of the incense went up with the prayers of the saints out of the hand of the Angel before God. And the Angel took the censer and filled it with the fire of the altar and cast it to the earth; and there were thunders and voices and lightnings and an earthquake. And the seven angels who had the seven trumpets prepared themselves to trumpet.

I agree that the silence conveys solemnity. The 7th seal, along with the 6th: the answer to the saints' prayers including in the 5th. And (the 7th) beginning the three and a half years of "tribulation such as has not occurred from the beginning of the creation which God created until now, nor shall by any means ever occur." Mk 13:19, 24; Dan 9:27; 7:25; Mt 24:21, 29

Comment: Thank you for reminding us of the prayers of all the saints (Revelation 6:9) that ascend even now as we approach the tribulation that announces the return of Christ Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare Matthew 24:4-8 with the 4 horseman you can see it is covering the same material as Rev 6, and the final seal in Rev 8.

> “See that no one leads you astray. 5For many will come in my name,
> saying, ‘I am the Christ,’ and they will lead many astray. 6And you
> will hear of wars and rumors of wars. See that you are not alarmed,
> for this must take place, but the end is not yet. 7For nation will
> rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and there will be
> famines and earthquakes in various places. 8All these are but the
> beginning of the birth pains.

The leading many astray being the overcoming that the white horse will cause. Nation against nation is the peace taken from the earth by the red horse. The famine, and wars and rumors of wars covers most of the Pale horse. The black horse is not mentioned.

So Matthew 24 starts with the same content that the seals cover, it then moves into the tribulation territory of Seal 5 which it says is cut short to prevent all those in the tribulation from dying. Matthew then goes on to say that immediately after this tribulation against the saints, the sun will go dark which begins the heavenly signs of Seal 6. Then the sign of the Son of Man appears in the sky, and his elect are gathered. This is the point where Rev 7 picks up, showing the 144,000 from every tribe being sealed on earth, and a separate group from all over the earth standing before the throne and the lamb. This group is the gathered elect from the Tribulation that we see in Matthew 24.

So perhaps the reason there is silence in heaven is because Jesus and His angels are gathering the elect. So you have seal 5, where those in the tribulation are asking when the judgement will begin, but are told their numbers are not yet complete. They reach completion, the 6th seal begins, sky goes dark, Jesus leaves heaven to gather His elect, leaving heaven silent for a half hour (perhaps very few left alive to gather), then when the elect are off the earth, and the 144,000 of the 12 tribes on earth are sealed, the 7th seal is broken which begins the wrath of God.

Answer (score 0):

Revelation 10:5-6 declares an end to time prophecies, but some, myself included, believe this only applies to attempts to set dates or times for apocalyptic events such as Jesus' coming, the close of probation, the seven last plagues, etc.  We are told we will not know when these things will take place.

That said, time itself obviously does continue, and the prophetic time formulae of the Bible do not cease to exist.

Prophecies in the Bible follow one of two time formulas:

1 day = 1 year (Numbers 14:34; Ezekiel 4:6)

1 day = 1 millennium (Psalm 90:4; 2 Peter 3:8)

Following the first of these formulas, one half hour would prophetically be equivalent to 1/48th of a day, and with one Biblical year consisting of 360 days (30 days for each month), this would yield 7.5 days.  Assuming it takes Jesus and his retinue of angels about half a day to come to earth to receive his saints, the next week will be spent in travel with those saints back to heaven, with some very likely sight-seeing along the way--imagine the joy of all heaven to provide the redeemed ones with their first guided tour of the universe!  With heaven empty during this time (all the angels would be coming along for this special occasion), heaven would be silent.

**Disclaimer:** This is one interpretation, and I am but one of many who adhere to it.  However, while I am convinced of parts of it--such as the week's journey to heaven, I am less sure of other aspects, such as whether Revelation is actually addressing the Second Coming at this point in the narrative.  The book of Revelation is special and takes time to understand the chronology of the events it portrays.  Consider this application a point from which to continue your studies, investigating further to see whether it may be so.  In any case, this is so far my best explanation for the half hour of silence.

Answer (score 0):

Noise in heaven (thunder and voices a few verses later) means God's wrath is now acting on the earth (next couple of chapters)
"Silence"means God's wrath is not yet acting.
"Half an hour" means the first half of the "hour" during which the beast rules (ch17 v12)

I explore this question and others in my book, ['Silence in Heaven: A Survey of the Book of Revelation'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597556734):

> “There was silence in heaven for about half an hour.”
>
> This interval takes place before the appearance of the trumpets. The
> enigmatic statement can be explained by reference to the rest of
> Revelation. Firstly, we must notice that in v5, when the trumpets are about to blow, there will be peals of thunder, voices, flashes of lightning, and an earthquake. The same kind of thing happens after the last of the trumpets, and again after the last of the bowls, signalling the approach of judgement. In other words, there is corresponding noise in heaven when God’s wrath is acting upon the earth. The obvious conclusion is that “silence in heaven” obliquely indicates a time when God’s wrath is not acting upon the earth.
>
> Then we are told later that the ten kings “receive authority as kings for
> one hour, together with the Beast” (ch17 v12). If we see “one hour” in part of Revelation, and “half an hour” in another, it seems reasonable to suppose that the two are connected. That is, the overall statement carries the meaning “The Beast rules for a certain period of time, and for the first half of that period God does not trouble it, does not try to destroy its power.”

Comment: Hi Stephen, you had not made it clear that this 'quote' was actually from your own work - please do make any self-attribution like this clear in future.